# Testing C Random Number Generator

Tags: c, arrays, random, numbers

I am working on a project and I am stuck on how to complete a specific part.

The assignment is "Write a program to determine whether or not the C random number generator really generates uniformly random number. You will do this by creating an array of 20 integers and then generating 200,000 random numbers between 0 and 19 (inclusive). **For each random number, n, that is generated, increment the nth element of the array by 1. If the C random number generator is uniform, then every element in the array should end up with roughly the same value.** To find out if this is the case, you will need to print the array. You will also need to print out the minimum and maximum values of the array, along with the mean and standard deviation."

*However*, I need help with the for each random number, n, that is generated, increment the the nth element of the array by 1. I am not really sure what is being asked or how to go about it. I am not asking for the code to do it, but what should I use in order to complete it.

I am fairly new to C so apologies in advance if this is an obvious answer.

Comment: This looks like homework - what code have you written so far.

Comment: That's a pretty trivial thing. I'm not even sure how to explain it without just giving the answer.

Comment: imagine that you have an array of 20 "buckets", so for each random number you generate, you check in which bucket it falls and increase the counter for each bucket; and at the end, you check the count for each bucket, if they have all (more or less) the same count, then your random numbers are generated uniformly.

Comment: Define more or less.

Answer (score 4):

This array might be descriptively named `count[20]`, with each element initialized to 0 before you start.  So the increment mentioned in the problem description is only adding 1 to the count for that random number.  For example, if 17 is generated, you increment count[17] every time that happens.  When finished, count[17] tells you how many times 17 came out of that generator.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code:

```
int bucket[20] = {0, };            // all values start at 0
for (int i = 0; i < 200000; ++i) { // you need 200000 random values
    int j = random(0, 20);         // produce a number between 0 and 19
    bucket[j] = bucket[j] + 1;     // increment the appropriate counter
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote -- did my pseudo-code miss the purpose of the question?

Comment: Perhaps it is OP's "I am not asking for the code to do it"?

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 20
#define TRIALS 200000

int
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int counter[SIZE] = {0};
    for (int trial = 0; trial < TRIALS; trial++) {
        counter[rand() % SIZE]++;
    }
    for (int idx = 0; idx < SIZE; idx++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%02d %d\n", idx, counter[idx]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The [`rand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) function generates a number between 0 and [`RAND_MAX`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/), which is guaranteed to be at least 32767. When you do a [modulus operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) on this value, where the modulus is less than `RAND_MAX`, you get a number between 0 and the modulus.

So the code `rand() % SIZE` generates a random value between 0 and 19, inclusive. You can use this value as an index for the array `counter`.

This should be enough for you to figure out min., max. and the rest of the statistical calculations.

Hint: 20 is not a multiple of `RAND_MAX + 1`, so that should tell you if the modulus operation can divide up random numbers evenly — uniformly — even before you do this exercise.

Comment: Do you think that the poster learns anything if people do their homework?

Comment: Not sure, but there are so many code snippets on the web that this homework assignment has probably been answered many times over. Mainly, I wanted to explain how `rand()` works, why the modulus operation can be used with `rand()` to solve the coding part of the problem, and to suggest that the original question ("Does a RNG generate uniformly random numbers within the given bounds?") can be answered without even doing any random sampling, based on the parameters provided.

Comment: The modulo bias is a combination of the cycle for the seed used by rand(), which is typically 2^32, modulo (RAND_MAX+1), and in this case modulo 20. Since 2^32 is normally a multiple of RAND_MAX+1, there's no issue there, but modulo 20 will create a bias. There's also a bias since only 200,000 of the 4,294,967,296 numbers cycled through by rand() are used.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Another way to think of it that is a little simpler is if you roll a four-sided die to get random numbers, and you apply `mod 3` on whatever number that comes up. In other words, the possibilities `{1, 2, 3, 4}` get mapped to `{1, 2, 3, 1}`. 1 is twice as likely to show up as 2 and 3, because 3 does not divide 4 evenly. Likewise, 20 does not divide `RAND_MAX + 1` evenly, and so some numbers will be over-represented (on average) and there will be non-uniformity in how random numbers are assigned to the bins 1 through 20 (or 0 through 19, depending on how you count).

Comment: If all 2^32 == 4,294,967,296 numbers were used modulo 20, then 4 "missing" numbers corresponding to 4,294,967,297 to 4,294,967,300 modulo 20 would cause a tiny bias. Each remainder 0 to 15 would occur 214,748,365 times, and each remainder 16 to 19 would occur 214,748,364 times. In the case RAND_MAX+1 == 2^15 = 32768, then on average, for each 32768 numbers, each remainder 0 to 7 would occur 1639 times, and each remainder 8 to 19 would occur 1638 times, for all 2^32 == 4,294,967,296 numbers, 0 to 7 would occur 214,827,008 times, and 8 to 19 would occur 214,695,936 times.